# How to place any view below any other view which is getting it's position from code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift2

I've created 4 subviews of white color & a yellow one as you can see in reference image I've shared below.

[image]

And I've programmatically changed the position of Tabbar from bottom to top just below to navigation bar as you can see in below image (When it is running in the simulator).

[image]

Now since I've constraints for that yellow view in image as follow

[image]

It is appearing just below to navigation bar but I want it to be displayed just below the Tabbar.

Since Tabbar is getting its position programmatically & other views (including yellow view) are getting their positions from the storyboard. 
And since storyboard UIelements are get settled before any other UIelement which are coming from the program or at least get their position from programmatically.

What could be the best way to achieve what I want.

Please refer my storyboard as well to get more understanding. (Refer Below image)
[image]

I also want to fit all 5 subviews in the space between tabbar & bottom of the screen. I want to calculate 1/5th of that space & assign this height to each subview. I'd later reduce few pixels to separate them.

Comment: Which is your view controller? i mean UIViewController or UITableViewController or UICollectionViewController?

Comment: Does the the yellow and the four white views exist in a container view? such as collectionView or stackView?

Comment: @AhmadF no it's not in any other view.

Comment: What should happen to to fourth white view at to bottom if you pushed all of them? it will not fully displayed.

Comment: @AhmadF please help me to first place yellow view at the right position. Am about to post other question after this for making all the size calculation.

Comment: I'll be glad to help! but first, I suggest to edit this question -without the need of posting another one- for giving more details and asking about handling the sizes...

Comment: @AhmadF I've added one more query into the same question as you suggested.

Comment: Could you add a photo of what the expected result? so I can guarantee that my answer should solve your issue.

Comment: @AhmadF I've solved it, am about to right it answers please edit my answer if you think it can be improved. Or if you've another approach better than mine please add your answer. But if think my answer is good please upvote it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138639/discussion-between-rais-iqbal-and-ahmad-f).

Answer (score 3):

Why not add the height of the tab bar to the yellow view's top position? That way, you'd set the constraint something like:

```
Fajar.top = top + 44
```

If the tab bar is always visible, then that should work. But of course, if the tab bar only appears at times, you'd probably have to change that constraint programmatically depending on the change ...

Comment: Don't just straight away put answer if you are not sure, instead comment on question.

Comment: As I said in the second sentence, "if the tab bar only appears at times, you'd probably have to change that constraint programmatically depending on the change".

So you'd have to get an IBOutlet for the layout constraint and change it as you need it. The hardcoding is the easy way - but you can change the constraint's constant value dynamically if you want - I just can't provide the code since I don't know what you're doing ...

Comment: I was sure of what I was saying, don't jump to conclusions without checking the facts :)